# How to implement a conditional JSON schema

Tags: java, json, rest, web-services, validation

I am using a JSON schema file, which has been used as a reference to validate against the JSON input in the Web-Service and for that i am using [everit](https://github.com/everit-org/json-schema/) library. Below is the code JSON schema file I am using.

```
{
 "oneOf": [
             {
             "type": "object",
                 "properties": {
                     "foo": {
                     "enum": ["firstValue"]
                 },
                 "bar": {
                     "type": "array",
                     "items": {"type": "number"}
                 }                               
             },             
             "required": ["foo", "bar"]
             },
             {
             "type": "object",
                 "properties": {
                     "foo": {                     
                     "enum": ["secondValue"]
                 },
                 "buzz": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "minLength": 10
                 }
             },
             "required": ["foo", "buzz"]
             }    
         ]
}
```

I need to validate 1 input at one time i.e. either "firstValue" or "secondValue". I do not want to validate my input having "firstValue" against the "secondValue" schema. So i used "oneOf" but that also does not help me and it'll check for "secondValue" schema if the "firstValue" schema input has any issue.

So i tried using Switch in my Schema file:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "switch": [
        {
            "if": {"properties": {"foo": {"enum": ["firstValue"]}}},
            "then": {
                "properties": {
                    "bar": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "items": {"type": "number"}
                    }
                },
                "required": ["foo", "bar"]
            }
        },
        {
            "if": {"properties": {"foo": {"enum": ["secondValue"]}}},
            "then": {
                "properties": {
                    "buzz": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "minLength": 10
                    },
                    "required": ["foo", "buzz"]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

but this does not seems to work at all. Looks like it does not validate against my input.

**Reference Links:**
For "oneOf": http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.6.29
For "switch": https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/64

Comment: Can you provide the inputs which you are validating?